# Apparent contour on brush strokes when saved as PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I'm assigned to create a logo. I wanted to use brush tool to create it, but when I save my design as a PNG, it seems to show the contour of the strokes I made, which looks very unprofessional. How could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like whatever source art you are using you have released several compound shapes.

To fix this just make sure the part(s) you want to cut out is on the top using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, select everything <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and use the Minus Front option from the Pathfinder panel.

[image]

It looks something like this.

[image]

Comment: Could this be the cause of multiple expanding/expand appearence,and filling with Live Paint.?

Comment: @KakucsDavid It absolutely could be.